# HTML dash table throws syntax error when html.Tr children have a single element and elements generated by for loop

Tags: python, plotly-dash

This is the code snippet where the first col is as "name" and then depending upon the size of array, other columns are published. But I can't find a way in dash to keep these elements in single html.Tr.

```
def compare(data1, data2):
    datasets = ['data1', 'data2']
    table_header = [
        html.Thead(
            children=[
                html.Tr(
                    children=[
                        html.Th("Name", rowSpan ="2"),
                        html.Th(dataset,  colSpan ="3") for dataset in  datasets
                    ]
                )      
            ]
        )
    ]

    table = dbc.Table(table_header, striped=True, bordered=True, hover=True)
    return table

Error:
html.Th(dataset,  colSpan ="3") for dataset in  datasets                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Desired output:
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
        <th colspan="3">data1</th>
        <th colspan="3">data2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
table_header = [
    html.Thead(
        children=[
            html.Tr(
                children=[
                    html.Th("Name", rowSpan="2"),
                    *[html.Th(dataset, colSpan="3") for dataset in datasets],
                ]
            )
        ]
    )
]
```

With this syntax it's clear that

```
html.Th("Name", rowSpan="2")
```

should be the first child and then it needs to do the list comprehension and pass each element resulting from the list comprehension as an argument.

Comment: In some cases where I end up as below, complains that children cannot be list of lists
`children=[
                      [html.Td(testcase, rowSpan="3") for testcase in testcases],
                      *[html.Td('Base') for dataset in datasets],
               ]`

Comment: The first `Td` shouldn't be surrounded with a list. Compare with my example.